# Any way to see a comparison of area51 proposals to each other?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, site-proposal

Is there any way to see some sort of graph or data comparing the area51 proposals to each other? Since most of them have different age, straight-forward comparison favors the older ones, so it's not clear enough.

For example, I would be interested in seeing the daily growth of proposal X compared with proposal Y, as if they were created on the same day. Is there some way to access that data?

Comment: To clarify, this is a request for information on the proposal and not the beta site?  As in, you want to be able to see growth in number of followers / committers?

Comment: @David no, this is the request for information on the beta sites themselves. For instance, comparing the number of new questions per day, or new users per day, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to award the bounty to [me for my app](https://stackapps.com/questions/1312/popularity-contest) (which is the same as the one Justin posted) :)

Comment: It's awesome! Still some bugs, though - some sites seem to list the whole 30 days even though they have been up for less time, and I can't switch from users to questions.

Comment: @Oak, thanks for pointing that out. It actually only supports Questions - no User stats at atll at the moment. I've fixed that. Which site has a full 30 days? Personal Finance? There's a note about that in there.

Comment: does this still work? Would be very useful, but it just sits at 'Loading' indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't deserve the bounty.  But see this app:

https://stackapps.com/questions/1312/popularity-contest